# How to hide Navigation bar behind master page in xamarin forms (Android plate form)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I working in xamarin forms. **I want to create masterDetail page where my Navigation bar is hide behind my master page (drawer menu) when we click on hamburger icon.** This functionality is automatically achieve in ios but not possible android. How is this possible in android?
I have referred following link and try to implement but unfortunately its not happening.

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Hanselman.Forms

**Is there any easy way to do this?**

**Is Custom theme really require?**

**What is use of tap and toolbar xml files?**

Comment: You master detail should be root page, not navigationpage. Then put navigation page as detail, you will achieve, what you want

Comment: No that's not an issue. I want to create custom theme which is helpful to hide my Action bar under my master page.

Comment: Did you get the solution ?